# How to add alt to image in custom section

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have created a custom section in which I add a picture. I need to display its alt. How can i do this?

```js
  <img src="{{ section.settings.img_section_image | img_url: '960x645'}}">

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Img section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "id": "img_section_image",
      "type": "image_picker",
      "label": "Add image"
    },
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Img sections"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you upload the image simply click on the image, and a popup appears on the popup there is a text field to add an alt tag for that image.

it looks like this image:
[image]

To get it on img tag you can use the default [image_tag](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/image_tag)

```
{{ section.settings.img_section_image | image_url: width: 200 | image_tag }}
```

it shows the alt tag automatically when img tag is created
or use the

```
{{ section.settings.img_section_image| image_url: width: 200 | image_tag: alt: 'My image's alt text' }}
```

To add manually custom tag, without backend.

if you do not use `image_tag`, then try something like this

```
<img src="{{ section.settings.img_section_image | img_url: '960x645'}}" alt="{{section.settings.img_section_image.alt}}">
```

I hope this will helps you and other as well